# How to draw a line into a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'm trying to replicate a picture like the following:
[image]

I'm only at the beginning stages of this replication, as a result I have the following:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations,pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}

\begin{document}

%% Set up the style
\tikzstyle{rom} = [square, draw, text width=5em, text centered,
  minimum height=4em]

\begin{tikzpicture}
  %% Start drawing the nodes
  \node[rom] (rom1) {ROM};
  \node[rom] (rom2) [below=of rom1] {ROM};

  \draw[->] (rom1.west)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

How can I go about drawing the A2, A1, & A0 lines going into the top node? My guess was, that we'll create an invisible node to the left, and then we can draw the lines from the invisible node to the drawn node?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, here's a simple way to draw the first one. Note that I had to change your code in several places as it would not compile without errors.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri}

\begin{document}

%% Set up the style
\tikzset{%
  rom/.style = {draw, text width=5em, text centered, minimum height=4em}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  %% Start drawing the nodes
  \node[rom] (rom1) {ROM};
  \node[rom] (rom2) [below=of rom1] {ROM};

  \draw[<-] (rom1.west) -- +(-20mm,0) node [left] (a1) {$A_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: first]

Looking at the picture as a whole, I would be inclined to use a `pic` to draw the ROM boxes because they are identical and the pattern of connections is always the same. You can then use a couple of loops to add several of the lines and finish with the more complex cases, handling those one-by-one.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
```

Load the libraries we want:

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

%% Set up the style
```

We use a counter to name the ROM boxes. The first will be `rom1`, the second `rom2` and so on.

```
\newcounter{rom}
\setcounter{rom}{0}
\tikzset{%
  rom/.style = {draw, text width=5em, text centered, minimum height=4em, font=\sffamily},
  a node/.style = {inner sep=1pt, font=\scriptsize},
```

Here comes the code for the `pic`, `rom node`:

```
  rom node/.pic = {%
```

Increment the counter:

```
    \stepcounter{rom}%
```

Draw and name the basic box:

```
    \node [rom] (rom\therom) {ROM};
```

Now we create the connections `rom<counter>-a0`, `rom<counter>-a1` and `rom<counter>-a2` on the left and label them.

```
    \foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {1/4,1/2,3/4} \node (rom\therom-a\j) [a node, right] at ($(rom\therom.south west)!\i!(rom\therom.north west)$) {$A_\j$};
```

Now for connections `rom<counter>-d0` and `rom<counter>-d1` on the right.

```
    \node (rom\therom-d1) [a node, left] at (rom\therom-a2 -| rom\therom.east) {$D_1$};
    \node (rom\therom-d0) [a node, left] at (rom\therom-a0 -| rom\therom.east) {$D_0$};
```

This is the label at the top:

```
    \node [a node, below] at (rom\therom.north) {$8 \times 2$};
```

Now we want connections `rom<counter>-oe` and `rom<counter>-ce` at the bottom.

```
    \node (rom\therom-ce) [a node, above, xshift=-10pt] at (rom\therom.south) {$CE$};
    \node (rom\therom-oe) [a node, above, xshift=10pt] at (rom\therom.south) {$OE$};
  },
```

A style for drawing the lines where one end is on another line would be useful.

```
  bullet arrow/.style={{Circle[width=2pt,length=2pt]}->, shorten <=-1pt}
}
```

Change the default arrow tip for the picture.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Latex[]}]
  %% Start drawing the nodes
```

Now for the two `rom node` `pic`s:

```
  \pic {rom node};
  \pic [below=of rom1] {rom node};
```

Using the connections from the `pic`s we can loop over the `d` connections on the right and add the arrows to `d0`, `d1`, `d2` and `d3`.

```
  \foreach \i/\j in {rom1-d1/3,rom1-d0/2,rom2-d1/1,rom2-d0/0}
  \draw [->] (\i) -- +(20mm,0) node (d\j) [a node, right] {$D_\j$};
```

Now for the arrows entering the higher ROM box on the left and for the connections from these arrows into the corresponding connectors in the lower ROM box. We mark the spots where the connections to the lower box should begin when drawing the arrows into the higher box and then add the connections from those spots using a second `\draw`.

```
  \foreach \i in {0,1,2}
  {
    \draw [<-] (rom1-a\i) -- +(-20mm,0) coordinate [pos=(3-\i)/6] (a\i x) node (a\i) [a node, left] {$A_\i$};
    \draw [bullet arrow] (a\i x) |- (rom2-a\i);
  }
```

Next, the arrows into `rom2-ce` and `rom2-oe`, marking the spots where we want to add further arrows later.

```
  \draw [<-] (rom2-oe) |- +(20mm,-5mm) coordinate [pos=.85] (oex) coordinate (oe);
  \draw [<-] (rom2-ce) |- ([yshift=-2.5mm]oe) coordinate [pos=.8] (cex);
```

And here are the later arrows connecting the marked spots to `rom1-oe` and `rom1-ce`.

```
  \draw [bullet arrow] (oex) |- ([yshift=-5mm]rom1-oe.south) -- (rom1-oe.south);
  \draw [bullet arrow] (cex) |- ([yshift=-7.5mm]rom1-ce.south) -- (rom1-ce.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ROMs]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,calc}

\begin{document}

%% Set up the style
\newcounter{rom}
\setcounter{rom}{0}
\tikzset{%
  rom/.style = {draw, text width=5em, text centered, minimum height=4em, font=\sffamily},
  a node/.style = {inner sep=1pt, font=\scriptsize},
  rom node/.pic = {%
    \stepcounter{rom}%
    \node [rom] (rom\therom) {ROM};
    \foreach \i [count=\j from 0] in {1/4,1/2,3/4} \node (rom\therom-a\j) [a node, right] at ($(rom\therom.south west)!\i!(rom\therom.north west)$) {$A_\j$};
    \node (rom\therom-d1) [a node, left] at (rom\therom-a2 -| rom\therom.east) {$D_1$};
    \node (rom\therom-d0) [a node, left] at (rom\therom-a0 -| rom\therom.east) {$D_0$};
    \node [a node, below] at (rom\therom.north) {$8 \times 2$};
    \node (rom\therom-ce) [a node, above, xshift=-10pt] at (rom\therom.south) {$CE$};
    \node (rom\therom-oe) [a node, above, xshift=10pt] at (rom\therom.south) {$OE$};
  },
  bullet arrow/.style={{Circle[width=2pt,length=2pt]}->, shorten <=-1pt}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Latex[]}]
  %% Start drawing the nodes
  \pic {rom node};
  \pic [below=of rom1] {rom node};
  \foreach \i/\j in {rom1-d1/3,rom1-d0/2,rom2-d1/1,rom2-d0/0}
  \draw [->] (\i) -- +(20mm,0) node (d\j) [a node, right] {$D_\j$};
  \foreach \i in {0,1,2}
  {
    \draw [<-] (rom1-a\i) -- +(-20mm,0) coordinate [pos=(3-\i)/6] (a\i x) node (a\i) [a node, left] {$A_\i$};
    \draw [bullet arrow] (a\i x) |- (rom2-a\i);
  }
  \draw [<-] (rom2-oe) |- +(20mm,-5mm) coordinate [pos=.85] (oex) coordinate (oe);
  \draw [<-] (rom2-ce) |- ([yshift=-2.5mm]oe) coordinate [pos=.8] (cex);
  \draw [bullet arrow] (oex) |- ([yshift=-5mm]rom1-oe.south) -- (rom1-oe.south);
  \draw [bullet arrow] (cex) |- ([yshift=-7.5mm]rom1-ce.south) -- (rom1-ce.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is much more than an answer --- it's a great tutorial. Thanks and bookmarked.

Comment: You're welcome! I hope it makes sense ;).

Comment: This is incredible. Much better than I could've expected, thanks so much. I'm quite late to the LaTeX game, I'm trying to convert a lot of my chicken scratch notes to something a little more formal.

Comment: @NicholasLand Thanks. As I say, I hope it makes sense. `pic`s are really useful. (Not quite as flexible as nodes, but much easier to make!)